# How to implement Exponential Power distribution in JAGS

Tags: r, bayesian, mixture-distribution, jags

I would like to fit a simulated data to Exponential Power likelihood using uniform mixture with gamma mixing presented in "[Scale Mixtures Distributions In Statistical Modelling](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1467-842X.2008.00504.x)" by Choy and Chan: $EP(x|\mu,\sigma,\beta) = \frac{c_1}{\sigma}exp(-|\frac{c_0^{1/2}(x-\mu)}{\sigma}|^{\frac{2}{\beta}})$, where $c_0 = \frac{\Gamma(3\beta/2)}{\Gamma(\beta/2)}, c_1=\frac{c_0^{1/2}}{\beta\Gamma(\beta/2)}$ are fixed functions of $\beta$. According to the authors the sampling hierarchy is $X|\mu,\sigma^2,\beta,u\sim U(\mu-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2c_0}}u^{\beta/2},\mu+\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2c_0}}u^{\beta/2})$ , $u|\beta\sim Ga(1+\frac{\beta}{2},2^{-1/\beta})$. I used JAGS in R with the below codes

```
Y <- rnorm(1000)
N <- length(Y)
jagsscript = cat("
model{

  for(i in 1:N){
    Y[i] ~ dunif(mu - d[i], mu + d[i])
    d[i] <- tau/pow(2*c0,0.5)*pow(u[i],beta/2) 
    u[i] ~ dgamma(1+beta/2,pow(2,-1/beta))
  }
  #prior
  beta ~ dunif(0.0001,2)
  sigma ~ dgamma(0.01,0.01)
  tau <- 1/sqrt(sigma)
  mu ~ dnorm(0,0.0001)
  c0 <- exp(loggam(3*beta/2)-loggam(beta/2))
}",file=model.loc)
```

Now I am stuck because I can't get this model to run since I might have Y observed outside of the boundaries of the uniform distribution. Is there a way to avoid this from happening or is there any better way to use JAGS to model an exponential power likelihood? Any help would be appreciated!